# Connecting to Spark using Apache Phoenix Spark plugin and running custom SQL queries

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

Could someone tell how to connect to Spark using Phoenix Spark connector rather than using Phoenix as a JDBC data source (This works if used as a JDBC source but performance is an issue https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html).

This is my attempt to do it with the Phoenix driver but it throws a "Table Not Found" exception.

```
sql = '(select COL1, COL2 from TABLE where COL3 = 5) as TEMP_TABLE'

df2 = sqlContext.read\
                .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")\
                .option("table", sql)\
                .option("zkUrl", "<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>")\
                .load()
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 139, in load
return self._df(self._jreader.load())
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1625.load.
: org.apache.phoenix.schema.TableNotFoundException: ERROR 1012 (42M03): Table undefined. tableName=sql
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PMetaDataImpl.getTableRef(PMetaDataImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection.getTable(PhoenixConnection.java:441)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.getTable(PhoenixRuntime.java:379)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.generateColumnInfo(PhoenixRuntime.java:405)
    at 

org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getSelectColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:279)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.toDataFrame(PhoenixRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRelation.schema(PhoenixRelation.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you prove here that table does exist?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, the table exists, I am able to use it by treating Phoenix as a JDBC data source.

Comment: @cricket_007, this is how it works with JDBC: 
`sql = '(select COL1, COL2 from TABLE where COL3 = 5) as TEMP_TABLE';

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(driver="org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver", url='jdbc:phoenix:<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>', dbtable=sql).load()`

Comment: But `dbtable=sql` isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `sql` variable is pointless... You need to create a whole Dataframe from `TABLE`. The `"table"` option  is not a SQL statement

You then use Spark's DataFrame API to `select` columns `COL1, COL2` and `filter` for `COL3 = 5`

You can see examples here that `TABLE1` is created, then used in the options, then (in the Scala examples), it's all Dataframe operations.

[Phoenix Spark](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)

In your case, once you load the table correctly, not using the `sql` variable, you'd have this

```
df3 = df2.select('COL1', 'COL2').where('COL3 = 5')
```

Or you're looking for how Spark APIs work outside of Phoenix...

Something like, [Running queries programmatically](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically)

You use the Dataframe for raw queries, not pass the query to the construction of the Dataframe

```
df = sqlContext.read\
            .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")\
            .option("table", "TABLE")\
            .option("zkUrl", "<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>")\
            .load()
#  df.createOrReplaceTempView("phoenix")  # Maybe necessary 

sqlDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE  where COL3 = 5")
sqlDF.show()
```

Comment: I am interested in knowing if the Phoenix Spark connector supports something along the lines of what the JDBC connector allows me to do. For eg., the below statements achieve the purpose using JDBC:

`sql = '(select COL1, COL2 from TABLE where COL3 = 5) as TEMP_TABLE'; 
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(driver="org.apache.ph‌​oenix.jdbc.PhoenixDr‌​iver", url='jdbc:phoenix:<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>', dbtable=sql).load()`